# Internet Sharing won't show under Share settings on OS X Server 10.6.8

Tags: osx-server, system-settings, internet-sharing

I need to use the Mac Mini Server running 10.6.8 as an access point for my team at the office.

When I go under `System Preferences`>`Sharing` there's no `Internet Sharing` Option.

What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The server OS doesn't offer the one-click Internet Sharing.  It can be done, although the server OS wants to be much more involved than the client OS.

- Go to your Server Admin.
- Select your server and click NAT (if you don't see it, click your server name, then click the `Services` tab at the right, then put a check-mark at `NAT`.  Now, back at the left hand panel, click the `NAT` service you just enabled.
- On the `Settings` tab, make sure `IP Forwarding and Network Address Translation (NAT)` is selected, and choose the proper `External network interface`.
- On the `Overview` tab, click the `Gateway Setup Assistant...` button.

At this point, unfortunately, I can't provide the details.  My 10.6.8 mini server is a DHCP client, so I can't continue with the assistant without altering my setup :(

Do reply though with the results of the `Gateway Setup Assistant...`

Comment: I have done this process like five times now, in `External network interface` there's just `Ethernet` available. but how do I get the other computers to join the network trough Mac Mini's AirPort?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem after some Apple update...

My solution:

1. download pref pane on the following website:

http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/

(the pref pane also works for Snow Leopard). This pref pane will allow you to quickly see in System Preferences if Apache and PHP are on and if not, you can switch it easily on again.

1. you might notice that in /etc/apache2/ you have a httpd.conf and a httpd.default.conf file present. First step: Copy httpd.conf to the desktop, second step: delete the httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2/ and, third step: rename httpd.default.conf to httpd.conf.
2. depending in your set-up you will have to take the '#' out on the LoadModule php5_module {and so on...} to re-enable php.
3. restart the web server.

Hope this helps.

Nick

Comment: That's nice but this is about `Web Sharing` and what I need is `Internet Sharing` to make the Mac Mini works as an `Access Point`, sharing the internet connection from Ethernet to AirPort, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Classic Internet Sharing like known from "consumer" MacOS X is not available in OS X Server. However, I found interesting hints in Apple’s [Advanced Server Administration](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/ServerAdmin_v10.6.pdf) for 10.6 Snow Leopard and [Apple’s support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.psp.more&locale=en_US&q=Snow%20Leopard%20Server%20Gateway%20and%20Firewall).

I think you want to configure *Internet Sharing* with **Server Admin**, which you should find in `/Applications/Server/`. I do not have a installation of OS X Server at hand, but there you should find *Service Configuration Assistants*. Apple description:

> Server Admin has configuration
>   assistants to guide you through setting up services that require more
>   setup than a single configuration pane. The assistants present you
>   with all configuration panes necessary to fully enable a service.

You want **Gateway Setup** in *Server Admin*:

> The NAT Gateway Setup Assistant helps you quickly and easily set up
>   Mac OS X Server […] to share your connection to the Internet with your
>   local network.

(taken from [Mac OS X 10.6 Server Admin: Understanding the NAT Gateway Setup Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH9106))

> This assistant helps you set up your server as a network gateway.
>   Launch the assistant using a button in the lower right side of NAT
>   service’s *Overview* page.

Configuration might be a bit more complex than with *Internet Sharing*, but I guess it should be manageable! Hope this helps.

Comment: Obviously, this is more or less a dupe of [Josh’s answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60786/26522). Hmmm.